# Memory leak (ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow) in simple block of code

Tags: c, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
  char *flags=malloc(1*sizeof(char));
  flags[0]='a';
  printf("%s\n",flags);
  free(flags);
  return 0;
}
```

No more, no less.

If I comment out the printf, no error occurs.

Why does it give me this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: NUL terminate the string before calling `printf`, (or use `calloc`), also, 1 byte is not enough to store "a", you need 2 bytes (one more for the trailing NUL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `printf("%s\n",flags);`, `flags` should point to memory that contain a *string*.

`flags` memory does not contain a *null chracter*, so is not a string.

Either 1, make allocated memory assigned to `flags` bigger and append a `'\0'` or 2, use a limited print: `printf("%.1s\n",flags);` or 3) print a `char`: `printf("%c\n",*flags);`